# What type is the `(...)` of the `IN` clause?

Tags: sql, types

I can write the following two statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers);
```

Does this mean that the `(...)` construction in SQL means it is a table of a single column? Or how is that type defined exactly?

Comment: Type is defined by the type of the colum selected in the subquery

Comment: @xQbert of course -- in the above it is a string. So what would be the type of `('Germany', 'France', 'UK')` ?

Comment: It all depends on particular RDBMS implementation. Eg in postgresql it's (at least) 2 different overloaded operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN

Comment: Well string since they are defined in ticks. But unsure if nvarchar or varchar.  as far as size I’d assume a varchar(max length of longest string or varchar max). Never really thought about it just knew it was treated as string. Implicit casting may be occurring to match type of customer country… but that seems like a strange foreign key…

Comment: @xQbert they ask about the entire `('Germany', 'France', 'UK')` expression type. In postgresql it would be a "composite type" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.6).

Comment: Interesting an array of undefined or array of strings or array of ….  Would think type would need to be consistent…. Something I’ll play around with… interesting question

Comment: @xQbert "would need to be consistent" --- not necessary, the operator could be overloaded (like it is in postgresql).

Comment: I feel this question (and some of the comments) implicitly address `SQL Server` (aka the microsoft's rdbms), but it would be ideal if it was a hint about it somewhere in the question (like an `sql-server` tag used)

Comment: @zerkms right in postgres specifically it treats the first as a composite/record type: `SELECT pg_typeof(('Germany', 'France', 'UK'))`  --> `record`.